# Move data from Cosmos DB to Azure data lake storage

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-lake

Can we move / load data to azure data lake storage from Cosmos DB. If it can be done what are the prerequisites?

New to to this any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is very broad. What specific issue are you running into? Please edit your question to be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [Azure Data Factory?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/)

You can use the existing activities such as [Copy From](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db#importexport-json-documents) on how to export documents from Cosmosdb, and this [Copy to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-store) to know about how to import data to Azure data lake.

Comment: Yes I have looked into ADF, we can move the data to ADLS. But I just want to know if there any prerequisites like setting up endpoint and any service to be created etc.

Comment: I dont think you need anything other than connection details, also have a look at cosmosdb as a source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db#azure-cosmos-db-as-source

Comment: Also you can think of change feed if you want to look at other option https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed

Comment: Thanks for sharing the detailed explanation. I got an idea on how to achieve it.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. And Data Factory is just one of many ways to move data between Data Lake and Cosmos DB. There's no single way to answer this question (a question that's off-topic as written, as it's very broad, with no specifics other than a general requirement of moving some data between two places). There is plenty of documentation that covers all Azure services, APIs, SDKs, etc.